# Can't Copy To Network Drive Using XCopy

Tags: command-line, backup, xcopy

I'd like to copy the contents of **D:\Documents** (a folder on a local hard-drive) to **Z:\Documents** (a folder mapped to a NAS device).

`xcopy.exe D:\Documents Z:\Documents /d /s /y`

- /d - copies all Source files that are newer than existing Destination files
- /s - copies directories and subdirectories, unless they are empty
- /y - suppresses prompting to confirm that you want to overwrite an existing destination file.

Fails saying:

> Access denied
>
> Unable to create directory - Z:\Documents

It's worth noting that `Z:\Documents` already does exist (and should exist, I want to copy files new/newly modified files into the existing folder).

If I reverse the source and destination the command works as expected, so I know both of the paths are correct.

If I open a command prompt and attempt to create a new directory in `Z:\` or create a new file inside of `Z:\Documents` I'm able to without issue, so I know I have write-access to the `Z:\` drive.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `xcopy.exe D:\Documents\* Z:\Documents /d /s /y /r`  add the /r flag. Also are you running it in an admin shell. Also, is the Z:\ drive ntfs or fat? I've also read a bunch about xcopy not liking hidden files, maybe mess w that attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I tried 3 actions to tackle this issue:

1. use /R, Use this option to overwrite read-only files in destination. If you don't use this option when you want to overwrite a read-only file in destination, you'll be prompted with an "Access denied" message and the xcopy command will stop running.
2. try use \\hostname\sharedfolder instead of the mapped label Z:\
3. run as administrator, and make it clear if you are using administrator or other use to net the sharedfolder. Both OK for my environment.

Comment: Network drives exist in the user context. Running a script as a different user, or as administrator, is a different context and so you won't have the same mapped drives.